# Rails 3: action mailer not usng the :from => parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Hi guys I'm trying to get emails running for a "Contact" page and the emails are coming through just fine but the problem is that the "from" field won't show my :from => "" that's inside my mailer method. The same thing happens with my recover password function which is below. The email which persists in the 'from' field is "myusername@gmail.com" from the smtp settings. Really appreciate the any help with this!

I'm using Gmail and setup my smtp settings like this:

### config/initializers/mailer_setup

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
     :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port                 => 587,
     :domain               => "mydomain.com",
     :user_name            => "myusername@gmail.com",
     :password             => "mypassword",
     :authentication       => "plain",
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
     }
```

### mailer/user_mailer.rb

```
   def reset_password_instructions(user)
     @user = user
     @url  = "http://localhost:3000"
     mail(:to => user.email,
          :from => "test@mydomain.com",
          :subject => "recover your password"
          )
   end
end
```

### views/mailer/rest_password_instructions.html.erb

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail typically doesn't let you set the `from` field for sending emails.  For this reason, a lot of people switch to other mail services like SendGrid.

If you google "Rails gmail from field" you'll unfortunately see all the other people who have struggled with this in the past.