# Action::Mailer not delivering mail to the recepients

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I tried to send mail to the user when his profile is being viewed. i.e When a user clicks on show of a particular contact that contact will be notified about the profile view. I did not get any errors. But there is some delay where i have triggered the mailer. And also it works fine in the console.  But the mail is not being sent to the recepient.

This is what I have tried so far.

**mailer.rb**:

```
class CustomerSupport < ActionMailer::Base
    def customer_support(contact) 
     mail :to => contact.email, :from => "sugukvs92@gmail.com", :subject => "profileviews"       
  end
  end
```

**setup_mail.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => "gmail.com",
   :user_name => "sugukvs92",
   :password => "**************",
   :authentication => "plain",
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

**controller.rb**

```
def show
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    CustomerSupport.customer_support(@contact).deliver

end
```

Do I need to add any gem to implement this?

**development.log**

Started GET "/contacts/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-16 10:48:07 +0530
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  [1m[36mContact Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts`  WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered customer_support/customer_support.html.erb (0.1ms)

CustomerSupport#customer_support: processed outbound mail in 11.9ms

```
Sent mail to suganya.gnanasekar@in.reportbee.com (1797.4ms)
Date: Wed, 16 Jul 2014 10:48:07 +0530
From: sugukvs92@gmail.com
To: suganya.gnanasekar@in.reportbee.com
Message-ID: <53c60b0f7e609_b993ec57901998d@ameex.mail>
Subject: customer support from Report Bee
 Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to example.com, </h1>
<p>
  You have successfully signed up to example.com,

</p>
<p>
  To login to the site, just follow this link: 
</p>
<p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
 </body>
 </html>
 Rendered contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1829ms (Views: 16.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: And what does it produces on console ?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371596/rails-3-action-mailer-not-usng-the-from-parameters?rq=1

Comment: @G.B I did not get anything. my application is working normally. But I could see some delay in my application where i have triggered ths mailer

Comment: ok. what is you exact question ?

Comment: Mail is not sent to the receipient

Comment: ya in my console i got mail sent to: 'recepient address'

Comment: i got 200 ok and everything is fine in my console

Comment: Did you check recepient's spam?

Comment: yes. just now i checked. No messages there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to raise run time errors using the following code.

I added these lines in
**development.rb** file.

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

I have done a very silly mistake. I had two-step verification turned on in my gmail account which I used for default `:from`.  So I disabled it and I got my application working.

Comment: Hmm. I have very similar console output and 2 step verification is turned off for my `:from` address, which is also gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I also done goofed and made a silly mistake.

I didn't have a:

```
mail(to: )
```

line in my mailer function.