# ActionMailer not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, gmail, actionmailer

I'm trying to create an mailer in my rails application. I believe I have everything configured correctly but I am not receiving the email.

## app/lib/tasks/email/daily_summary.rake

```
namespace :email do
  desc 'Send Daily Summary Email'
  task :send_daily_summary, [] => :environment do
    DailyMailer.summary_email(ENV['GROUP_MAIL_ADDRESS'])
  end
end
```

## app/views/daily_mailer/summary_email.html.erb

```
<% if @new_apps.count >= 1 %>
<h1>
  <%="#{@new_apps.count} new Applications were added today" %>
</h1>
  <% @new_apps.each do |app| %>
    <p>
      <%= image_tag app.icon_url %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= app.name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= app.last_build %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<% if @new_versions.count >= 1 %>
<h1>
  <%="#{@new_versions.count} new builds of Applications were added." %>
</h1>
  <% @new_versions.each do |version| %>
    <p>
      <%= image_tag version.icon_url %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= version.app_name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= version.build_number %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

## app/mailers/daily_mailer.rb

```
class DailyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def summary_email(email_address)
    @new_versions = Version.since(24.hours.ago)
    @new_apps = App.since(24.hours.ago)
    mail(to: email_address, subject: 'Daily Summary - ')
  end
end
```

## config/environments/development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               ###############,
    user_name:            ENV['EMAIL_LOGIN'],
    password:             ENV['EMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

## output

```
rake email:send_daily_summary
    (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "apps"  WHERE (created_at > '2015-03-05 17:13:12.405508')
    (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "versions"  WHERE (created_at > '2015-03-05 17:13:12.345107')
    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "versions"  WHERE (created_at > '2015-03-05 17:13:12.345107')
   Version Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "versions".* FROM "versions"  WHERE (created_at > '2015-03-05 17:13:12.345107')
   App Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps"  WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
   Rendered daily_mailer/summary_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (97.8ms)

DailyMailer#summary_email: processed outbound mail in 440.8ms
```

Comment: You forget to post error from development.log log or console log.

Comment: @maxd I am not getting an error the take ends with `DailyMailer#summary_email: processed outbound mail in 440.8ms`

Comment: OK so the error ends with that, but what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751573/actionmailer-not-delivering-mail-to-the-recepients) is very similar questions.

Comment: @maxd Thanks for the link. However the problem still persist and I don't see any errors still

Comment: So, you have enabled `raise_delivery_errors` and `perform_deliveries` options in your development.rb file. Right?

Comment: yes they are both set to true @maxd

Comment: So, seems like the e-mail message was sent. 1) Spam directory is empty in your recipient account 2) ENV (i.e. GROUP_MAIL_ADDRESS) variables  initialized and doesn't have mistakes. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `.deliver` from your `DailyMailer.summary_email(ENV['GROUP_MAIL_ADDRESS'])` call.

should be:

```
DailyMailer.summary_email(ENV['GROUP_MAIL_ADDRESS']).deliver
```